# spring-boot:run doesn't load profiles

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Spring Boot Maven plugin lacks of examples with profiles

While repackage goal loads profiles properly:

`mvn spring-boot:repackage -Dspring.profiles.active=stage`

run goal doesn't load profile this way:

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=stage`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid miss the variables while spring-boot:run forks the process while launching use -Drun.jvmArguments

`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=stage"`